# What happens if post gets major edit after a few reopen votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

Once the question gets closed and some users cast reopen votes, the original post gets edited by the author and there is a big change.

Now the reopen votes that were cast before editing somewhat become useless as they meant to reopen the question in the previous state and may or may not like the present edited form of the question.

Should the question still be reopened if it gets other required reopen votes and count the previously cast votes too?

Comment: This is a far edge case that probably isn't worth worrying about much. If the *current state* of the question is such that it should be opened, the final votes will open it.  If it's not in a state where it should stay open, more close votes can close it.

Comment: Ok so in that case after reopening more close votes will again close the question.

Comment: Yeah, this is really no different than any other mistakenly closed/opened question (or closed then edited question). We can just keep voting on it until it reaches the final state it should be in.